# AngularJS 1-time-bind HTML

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do one-time-binding with html `ng-bind-html` directive?

For instance, i have:

`<span>{{::helpText}}</span>`

but my helpText is a html string so I have to do:

`<span ng-bind-html="helpText"></span>` which does 2-way-binding.

Comment: Not really clear what your issue is

Answer (score 4):

```
<span ng-bind-html="::helpText"></span>
```

should do the job.